# Blank report in Data report from Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, report

So,  i am trying to display the content of the datagridview into a datareport. But after linking the report via Dataset, the report generated is blank,  the code is here:

```
  Dim dt As New DataTable
  With dt

     .Columns.Add("Roll")

     .Columns.Add("Name")

  End With


  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

     dt.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(0).Value, DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value)

  Next


   Form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Item(0).Value = dt

   Form2.ShowDialog()
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("YourDataSet", dt)

Form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
Form2.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
Form2.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)